# SharePoint 2010 send WorkFlow email on form submit/save click

Tags: email, sharepoint-2010, workflow

Could you please help me understand how to send a workflow email, when user submits a task form. The process is to automate the sending of email to "BI Owners", when user fills out a form and once he/she clicks "save"/"submit", then the email should be sent out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to understand the Worfklow's configuration?
In that case, check this out:

[Send e-mail in a workflow](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-HA010239042.aspx)

How do you build up your form? It is an aspx, a webpart, some kind of magic?

Well, this is important, 'cause you have different ways to fire up your workflow, depending on that.

If you have all the form's control, well, this is my sending emails class:

```
  protected void sendEmail()
    {
        try
        {
                string mailTo = dudeToSendMail;
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                message.From = new MailAddress(mailSender);
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailTo));
                message.Subject = mailSubject;
                message.Body = buildMail();  // hey, dude, build up your mail here!
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }



    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. I appreciate it. The sample code helped me with understanding my own code.